# is it possible to create an account using Cleos?

Tags: cleos, accounts, mainnet, keosd

I've bought EOS on exchange recently and may not has an account on mainnet. So I really want to create an account prior before mainnet gets ready.

I understand that if we install full note and connect to EOS mainnet then we will be able to create account. However due to lack of resource, I don't want to install a Node.

So is that possible to just use Cleos and keosd to connect to Mainnet to create an account?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. 
To create an account in Mainnet, you need to use `cleos -u MAINNET_API_URL system newaccount` instead of `cleos create account`, since the back one is for boot 
 or development purpose, you can't create an account in Mainnet in this way.

Comment: I tried but not success:  
  
<b>cleos  --url http://130.211.59.178:8888 --wallet-url http://localhost:8899  system newaccount  manheos EOS5tWG4JeBJ3bP7GKyQmk7RPT.......  </b>
  <b>
ERROR: RequiredError: OwnerKey
Create an account, buy ram, stake for bandwidth for the account
Usage: cleos system newaccount [OPTIONS] creator name OwnerKey [ActiveKey]</b>

Comment: I guess manheos is the account name you want to create. You must set creator name, e.g. `cleos --url 130.211.59.178:8888 --wallet-url localhost:8899 system newaccount eosio manheos OWNER_PUBLIC_KEY ACTIVE_PUBLIC_KEY --stake-cpu "0.0001 EOS" --stake-net "0.0001 EOS" --buy-ram "0.0001 EOS"`

Comment: And for creator, it has to be producer name for now. This means for now you can't create an account by yourself, you need ask producer to create an account for you, and what you need to do is create two pairs of keys(owner and active), and give public key to producer for create account. In this way, after account created, you have the private key of the account, which means you own the account.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can just create wallet using the command: ./cleos wallet create
2. You can use scatter (see https://medium.com/@eosnewyork/your-vote-matters-4-how-to-vote-on-the-eos-mainnet-ca1b02ebcde1) -- use generate key pair, but use with caution as it is not an official application

Answer (score 0):

This command works:

```
cleos -u https://public.eosinfra.io:443 system newaccount  --stake-cpu "0.001 EOS" --stake-net "0.001 EOS" --buy-ram "0.2 EOS" [creator] [newusercreated] [ownerpublickey] [activepublickey]
```

Answer (score -1):

`./cleos create account`, `cleos` is a tool that eos.io officially release, use `cleos` rather than scatter.