# Where can i find complete step to create wallet and account on mainnet EOS?

Tags: accounts, wallet

I have bought some eos on binance. Now i m looking a way to create a wallet on eos mainnet in order to get my eos from binance. But There is no simple way and decentralized information about HOW to create a wallet and account.

I find this links https://eosnodes.privex.io/. After hours of problems (mongo-c-driver problems, api plugin not installed etc.., not working on debian, but i have a mac, gettext missing) i finaly successfuly run nodeos.

Then, i find how to have private public key on this link : https://nadejde.github.io/eos-token-sale/

I created wallets , following the github tutorial https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/wiki/Tutorial-Comprehensive-Accounts-and-Wallets
, i unlocked my wallets

And i followeds comments in this post https://eosio.stackexchange.com/a/812/1600 ( sees comments from spartacus) in order to create an account...

Here is my last step :

```
cleos -u http://130.211.59.178:8888 --wallet-url http://localhost:8899   system newaccount --stake-net "0.1000 EOS" --stake-cpu "0.1000 EOS" --buy-ram-kbytes 8 eosio myDesiredAccountName FIRST_PUB_KEY SECOND_PU_KEY
```

For what i have understood, FIRST_PUB_KEY is the key from the account eosio
and the SECOND_PUB_KEY is a key generated by myself from the above link generator.

And then this is the last message i have when running previous command :

```
Error 3120006: No available wallet
Ensure that you have created a wallet and have it open
Error Details:
You don't have any wallet!
```

Where do i find the FIRST_PUB_KEY ? Tutorial speak about config.ini ... 
located at
    ~/Libraries/Application Support/eosio/nodeos/config/config.ini

But.. there is no eosio directory at this place, eosio directory is where i compiled eos /Users/bryan/eosio/
But.. still no config.ini , however following this link https://eosnodes.privex.io/?config=1 i have created a file to contains nodes.

Is there a complete tutorial where i can have ALL elements and each step to complete, wallet and account creation and mainnet?

0 Generate two pairs of keys from the online generator
1 create wallet with a name and to import the two privates keys
2 save the password in safe place
3 unlock wallet with password
4 create account using goods urls...
5 getting stuck with message mentionned above.

what i m missing?

Answer (score 2):

> I have bought some eos on Binance. Now i m looking a way to create a wallet on eos mainnet in order to get my eos from Binance. But There is no simple way and decentralized information about HOW to create a wallet and account.

Please confirm Binance are allowing withdrawals and that they aren't offering an account creation service.

Accounts can only be registered by another EOS account on the main net as it costs to do so.

Wallet wise, we'll take it from the start. If you have cleos installed on your local machine then keosd should run in order to create a wallet.

Create a blank wallet with

`cleos create wallet`

This will return a password to open the wallet, store this safe, write it down, make sure you have a copy of this outside of your computer generating it.

Create a new EOS keypair on your local computer using cleos, this is the best method IMO, it's bad practice to use random key generators on the net.

`cleos create key`

Now, we can import this into the wallet with

`cleos wallet import *Private Key*`

It should return the public key back, copy this in your clipboard.

> For what i have understood, FIRST_PUB_KEY is the key from the account eosio and the SECOND_PUB_KEY is a key generated by myself from the above link generator.

No, `FIRST_PUB_KEY` and `SECOND_PUB_KEY` are both for your account, the first public key determines the public key for the owner permission, the second determines the active permission. Both of these keys are something only you know and generate.

In this example, we can use the same public key twice, however, if you'd like to be more secure then just repeat the commands.

`cleos create wallet`

`cleos import wallet *private key*`

*Clipboard the returned public key*

To create an account, assuming the IP in the -u switch is http://130.211.59.178:8888 is an endpoint which goes to the main net.

```
cleos -u http://130.211.59.178:8888 system newaccount --stake-net "0.1000 EOS" --stake-cpu "0.1000 EOS" --buy-ram-kbytes 8 eosio myDesiredAccountName *Clipboard key* *Clipboard key*
```

Comment: ok thanks for the details i was misuderstanding. but account creation still not working. Your second sentence, "Accounts can only be registered by another EOS account".. well, it seems, without the help of someone or third party, i will not able to create account? 

No withdrawal is not possible at this time on binance.

Comment: Then no, until Binance figure out what they're doing... 
They might offer an account facet service where they'll create an account for you and you go there. 
Correct, you need a 3rd party to create your account.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have an EOS account yet, you need to go through an account creation service like the one I created: https://eos-account-creator.com/

Once your new EOS account is created, you can withdraw your EOS tokens to it.